# Django Check Constraint for MySQL 5.7 alternatives

Tags: mysql, django, constraints

To my dismay (after being so excited to use it), CheckConstraints are not available on MySQL DBs less than 8.0.16.  I'm using MySQL 5.7 and doesn't look like I'll be updating any time soon.

I'm using Django v2.2 and wanted to apply the new constraints to my DB:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/

(The docs may need to be updated to say that check constraints don't work with MySQL versions less than xyz)

I want to know if anyone has a good working alternative for this use case.

I've currently whipped up a signal on pre_save to raise an IntegrityError if the constraint matches.

```
@receiver(pre_save)
def object_constraint(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if issubclass(sender, MyClass):
        if instance.constraint_is_met:
            raise IntegrityError("What are you even...?")
```

Thanks

Comment: Write a before insert/update trigger check the constraints and quit update or inserting.

Comment: @nbk Yeah, thanks for the suggestion, I was hoping not to touch the DB directly and rather have Django handle it either through a migration or other.

The other alternative I'm considering is Validators:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/